# VS2010 "Add Item" directory change

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to change the default directory Visual Studio 2010 uses when you add a source file through Add -> New Item?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? As far as I know you can only change the default location for new projects

Comment: @Rewinder because I find it messy to have source, headers, resources and project files in the same place. I don't like the fact the VS dumps everything in the one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since my comment seems to be the actual answer, I repost:

In the toolbar of Solution Explorer, there's a button "Show all files" (or similar, I'm using the German version). This switches the view to directories, rather than filters. In this view, you can right-click on the desired target folder to add items.

This does not actually change the default directory, but since you *have* to click *somewhere* anyway to add an item, this is the easiest approach.

Note that even when only using Visual C++, I'd recommend the Productivity Power Tools extension, which comes with Solution Navigator. In C++, this is not as powerful as with .NET, but it still has several features that are useful in C++ and can fully replace Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

`Add New Item` simply adds the item based on which project directory you're currently in or have selected in your Solution Explorer. If you want to change where it gets added then select the target location in the Solution Explorer first.

This behavior is obvious when right-clicking in the Solution Explorer, but it's also the same when using `Project -> Add New Item...`.

Comment: I want to change where it gets added withing that project, in a ./src for example, so that all .c files are not next to the vcxproj files

Comment: @dotminic not sure I follow. Are you trying to sort by file extensions?

Comment: @dotminic: What's wrong with right-clicking on the src directory in your example, and selecting Add New Item from there? Or is the problem that you are using Visual C++ in the filter view (Sources/Headers/Resources etc.), rather than using directory view, which I prefer for larger projects anyway?

Comment: @OregonGhost what is the directory view ? I'm just using the solution explorer, and to keep the project dir a little cleaner I want to put my source files in an src dir that is in my project dir.

Comment: @dotminic: In the toolbar of Solution Explorer, there's a button "Show all files" (or similar, I'm using the German version). This switches the view to directories, rather than filters. Note that even when only using Visual C++, I'd recommend the Productivity Power Tools extension, which comes with Solution Navigator. In C++, this is not as powerful as with .NET, but it still has several features that are useful in C++ and can fully replace Solution Explorer.

Comment: @OregonGhost post that as an answer and I'll upvote it. Hopefully @dotminic can accept it as an answer too since it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to tools -> options -> Project and Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old... but maybe someone will stumble upon it... like I did today...

I had the same "problem":

I have a dedicated directory for icons.

When I need to add an icon to the resource file, Visual studio takes me to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"

To fix the problem, after I "browsed" to the desired folder, I right-clicked the favorites of the "open file" dialog and selected "add current location to Favorites".

Next time you will get this dialog, you simply have to look for the folder in the favorites, and click it.