# Default directory where new classes are stored?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a c++ project in Visual Studio 2010. if I right click my project in visual studio and select Add->Class, it will create a .h and .cpp file in the same directory where my .sln file is.

How can I set a different default folder where the created files should be stored?

Comment: Root of Solution or Project? Should be project. Adding a class into solution makes no sense for me.

Comment: mmmmh - our cMake buildsystem places sln and vcxproj in the same directory - so, yeah, probably rather root of project

Comment: It is an option when you start a new solution from the IDE, "Create directory for solution" checkbox.  Clearly your CMake scripts have a mind of their own, find the guy in your team that knows something about it.

Comment: I don't care whether solution and project are in the same folder. i just want my new classfiles to go into ../../src/ (if the current directory is the one of the project)

Comment: this question has a nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031145/vs2010-add-item-directory-change)

Comment: Little things like this have me thinking XCode isn't all bad.

Answer (score 6):

Prefix the class filename (and header filename) with the desired location relative the .sln project file.

To have Visual Studio create your class in your `src` directory:

1. Type `src/` in front of the filename. This will weirdly disappear (in VS2017 at least) but on hitting OK the files get put in the right place.
2. In the Solution Explorer, drag the newly created files into the `src` (or desired) filter, this will update the project file (but won't move anything on disk).

[image]

Comment: This works for me on VS2017 Win10 Pro. Don't put `src/` in the class name box, just in the filename boxes. It puts the file in the correct directory - you'll still need to move it manually to any filters within the Solution Explorer

Comment: Why isn't the Location chosen in the Add > New Item... dialog box used as the location of the header and source file?

Answer (score 2):

No, by default Visual Studio will put a new item in project's root.

Comment: doesn't seem to make a difference whether I rightclick on the project and say 'add' or rightclick on a filter and say 'add' - always added in the same place

Comment: Yes, because filters do not represent the folder structure in the file system. Unfortunately, file handling in VS is rather tedious in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to always right click on the project / solution when you wish to **Add** something to your project and then make use of the **Location** edit box in the file dialog that VS throws up in order to put your items into the right place. Visual Studio *seems* to remember that location for the rest of your coding session but, annoyingly, promptly forgets it if you close and reload your solution or quit VS.

I use the method above for manually creating the .cpp and .h files when creating a class too. I stopped using the **Add Class** menu item option a while back because, as you've discovered, it offers no way to set the location of where the resultant files will go. Having to right click on a project, selecting **Open Folder in File Explorer** from the menu to bring up Windows' file Explorer, then cutting & pasting the class .h and .cpp files into the folders where I wanted them quickly became tedious.

I too would like to know if there are better ways to 'wrangle' Visual Studio into working with the way we physically construct our projects' folders in a more seamless and integrated manner. Maybe the VS team need to extend Solution Explorer to help with physical folder structure rather than being restricted to logical filters? I suspect there are non-trivial reasons behind why this hasn't been done yet though.

Comment: Tedious but functional. Would be nice if Add > New Item... Class would respect the selected location.

Answer (score 0):

A way around this is to use Add->New Item and then add the cpp and header file individually. A bit more work, but for some reason you can choose the folder when using New Item.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Add - New Item..." a CLASSNAME.h in your Project group then choose the right folder
2. "Add - New Item..." a CLASSNAME.cpp in your Project group, use last remembered folder
3. "Add - Class - C++ Class" and type CLASSNAME in the class name box first.
4. Use .h file / .cpp file to search for the classes created.
5. OK. The snippet for a new class will be merged into the empty cpp/h files you created before.

Answer (score -1):

you need to right click on the folder you want to add these new files and then go through the same process of adding a file.

Comment: click on the folder? you mean filter?

Comment: Sorry, I meant right click on the folder where you want to add the file.

Comment: it doesn't seem to make a difference whether I rightclick on the project or on a filter (Source Files for example), the files will be placed in the same directory as the projectfile

Comment: but what do you mean by 'folder'? do you mean inside visual studio the filters (which look like folder icons)?

Comment: if I want to add a file to AccessProviders folder in the image here: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/Images/Articles/MigratingToASP.NET2/ProvidersSolutionExplorer.gif I will right click on that folder and say Add File and then press Ok and you will see a file creatd under that folder

Comment: I have a c++ project - probably I should state that in the OP

Comment: C++ projects don't have folders that reflect the filesystem. They have filters for grouping files together.

Comment: exactly - I still want the created files to be stored in a folder differently from the folder that contains the projectfile. I can do this by creating a new item and then manually set the path where it shall be stored (does not work for add->class, only for add->new item) - but that's tedious